# How do I recover the items in a chest in my spouse's home that disappeared after moving?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I married Sylgja before I had my own home (I know her clothes aren't all that appealing but console commands yo) and I left my alternate armor sets in the chest at the foot of her bed.

Later I had her move into Honeyside in Riften with me but when I returned for my other armor at her old house (after LOTS of important quests, mind you), it was all gone and there was just a ruby and some gold in the chest.

I want to know if all of my gear is gone forever or if there's a place in my home, her home, or, well, anywhere, where I can get it back.

Comment: Acourding to UESP [Sylgja's house](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sylgja%27s_House) resets every 10 days.  Your stuff is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sylgja's house is not on the list of safe container locations provided by [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Places-Safe) or [The Elderscrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Containers_%28Skyrim%29#List_of_non-resetting_containers).  This unfortunately means that your items are likely to have been lost forever when the container reset.  Irritating when she is your spouse, but apparently an oversight by Bethesday.